# click one div change another's position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i cant seem to find the problem in my code.
I want to click the #menu and it will slide the #menudrop from the right.

```
#menudrop {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    right: -9999px; /* get element out of viewport */
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}
#menu{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:200px;
  background-color:black;
}

<div id="menu"></div>
<div id="menudrop"></div>

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#menu').Click(function(){
$('#menudrop').css('right', '0px');
 });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/theUnderdog/n60guhkq/

Comment: You need to include jQuery in your fiddle. I think $('#menu').Click should have a lowercase c in click. There may be other problems

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues in your code,

There is no function like `C`lick (capital C used) available with jquery its `click`,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#menu').click(function(){
  $('#menudrop').css('right', '0px');
 });
});
```

And its very important to include jquery library into our page before using it.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/n60guhkq/3/)